# How to save Python dataset (previously exported from IDL) back to IDL format

Tags: python, type-conversion, export, idl-programming-language

I have a file in IDL, I import it to Python using readsav from scipy, I change a parameter in the file and I want to export / save it back to the original format, IDL readable.

This is how I import it:

```py
from scipy.io.idl import readsav
input = readsav('Original_file.inp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested any of this, but here are a few options to try:

### Python-to-IDL/IDL-to-Python Bridge

The [Python to IDL bridge](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/PythonToIDL.html) provides a way to run IDL routines within python. You could try the following

```
from idlpy import *
from scipy.io.idl import readsav
input = readsav('Original_file.inp')
**change parameter**
IDL.run("SAVE, /VARIABLES, FILENAME = 'New_file.sav'")
```

There is also an [IDL to Python bridge](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/idltopython.html), which might allow you to perform your desired Python operation within IDL, and skip all the loading and saving of files...

### Read/Write JSON

It looks like `readsav()` just returns a dictionary of the contents of the IDL save file. I'm not sure of the contents of your file, so I don't know if this would work, but perhaps you could just write it as a JSON string,

```
import json
from scipy.io.idl import readsav
input = readsav('Original_file.inp')
**change parameter**
with open('New_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(modified_input, outfile)
```

and then read it back into IDL with `JSON_PARSE()` (documentation [here](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/JSON_PARSE.html)).

### Write your own hack

If all else fails, you could look at Craig Markwardt's [Unofficial Format Specification
of the IDL "SAVE" File](http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/savefmt/), and write some custom code to write an IDL save file directly from Python. If nothing else, it would be an interesting exercise.